# How can I temporarily prevent a form from getting focus/activating?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

my application opens n forms and the user can freely switch back and forth among these forms.
When the user decides to confirm the operations performed on one of the forms, I would like to block the other ones until this process (which can potentially open MessageBoxes and/or other forms) comes to an end. 
It is not enough to disable the forms, since the user can't do anything on them, but the Activated event is fired, and this is exactly what I want to avoid.
I tried to set ControlStyles.Selectable to false to all these forms, but it doesn't work.

Just in order to make it clearer, the forms cover the whole screen, so the users activate them clicking on the taskbar. This is the situation where opening a modal form and having the confirm code executed there does not prevent the Activated event to be fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Form.ShowDialog` Method method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

Comment: Mmm, sounds good but not enough. You are suggesting to open a new form with ShowDialog and to do the confirm work in its shown event, right? In this way all the other forma are disabled, but I can still select them and the Activated event is fired. And this is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I checked it at my end using the following approach. I created two forms in the sample application. Form1 and Form2. In Form1 there is a button and form activated event. On clicking the button opens the form2 in show dialog and now I tried to clicked form1 which is lying at the back side of form 2, this does not make the form1 activated event active. I verified it using break point and control never came over it. Please confirm whether the approach is ok ?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, you're right, it all works as you describe. It did not work for me since I switched to another form clicking on windows taskbar.

Comment: this.Hide();
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.ShowDialog(); //On closing the form 2 again set it's visibility //to true
this.Show();

Comment: OK, this works. I'd prefer to keep it visible, but can cope with that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method.